# Catch all redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is the htaccess file. I'm wanting to add a catch-all 301 redirect RewriteRule.

This is not working. Any ideas?

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$1 http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

Here are the rest of the rewrites.

```
enter coOptions +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

### HTTP > HTTPS & non WWW to WWW version
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.co.uk/%1 [NE,L,R=301]

### index.php & index to root domain
RewriteRule ^index(?:\.php)? http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]

### special rewrite rules for shortened urls ##
RewriteRule ^section(?:\.php)?/(.*)$ /s/$1 [R=301,L]
### To remove section page if 1 which is default for most (unless products span more)
RewriteRule ^s\.php/(.*)/1/(.*) /s/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^product(?:\.php)?/(.*)$ /p/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^article(?:\.php)?/(.*)$ /a/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^discount(?:\.php)/(.*)$ /d/$1 [R=301,L]

### Core Jshop .php removal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\.php/(.*)$ $1.php?$2 [L,QSA]de here

Redirect 301 /blog http://www.domain.co.uk/a/8/nursing-home-news/

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$1 http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your rewrite rules are in an htaccess file then you need to remove the leading slash from your rule's pattern as RewriteRule's regex matches against a relative old path starting without a `/` .

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks, it redirects everything now and the site won't load.

I'm wanting this catch-all 301 for all unfound pages to replace the traditional way these are dealt with by a 404.

Comment: To redirect only 404 uris you could put these two condition lines above the rule

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: @Puzzel Could you please be spacific about the the issue and what didn't work.?

Comment: Sure, when that was added the site didn't load

Comment: Any other ideas on this ?